# Get current post id in functions.php

Tags: posts, wp-query, functions, id

I have a `wp_localize_script()` function in my functions.php where I need to push the current post ID of the current post to a jQuery file. So I was wondering how you can get the current post ID of a post in my functions.php.

These are both not working:

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;

global $wp_query;
$post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you hook your localize script function to `wp_enqueue_scripts`, then you will have access to the `global $post` variable.  As long as you pick a hook at or after 'wp' you should have access to the `global $post`.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'YOUR_NAME_scripts'); 

function YOUR_NAME_scripts() {

            wp_enqueue_script('YOUR_NAME-js');

            global $post;
            $params = array(
                'site_url' => site_url(),
                'admin_ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                'post_id' => $post->ID
            );

            wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'YOUR_NAME', $params );

}
```

Comment: Is there any other workaround, as a standalone function for example, instead of inside `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

Comment: Yes, just hook into wp_head and echo script tags with `var post_id = <?php echo $post->ID;?>;`  Just make sure to use `global $post;` first.  Or echo your script tags anywhere in the Page/Post Template if you really want.